# Tell me how to set a link for component v-list-group

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Took an example of navigation from the site vuetifyjs.com, [[Expansion Lists]](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101) how to add links to this component?

```
<v-list-item-content>
    <v-list-item-title v-text="subItem.title"></v-list-item-title> //how to specify the link address
</v-list-item-content>
```

Answer (score 6):

For external links:

Just set the `href` attribute/prop on the `<v-list-item>` element.

Template style:

`<v-list-item :href="'../index.html'">`

Render function style:

```
 createElement('v-list-item',
          { attrs: { href: '../index.html' } },
          [             
            createElement('v-list-item-content', {}, ['Index'])
          ]
        )
```

OR for internal routes:

Use the `to` prop on `<v-list-item>`